# How can I prevent a page from rendering unless params[:userid] is an Integer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, boolean-expression

I'm trying to prevent the page from showing unless a `params[:userid]` is an integer.

I know the code is being called, because its not throwing errors, its not rendering, and I manually told it to render, then not render to check.

Here is what I'm using to try and do it:

```
render nothing: true unless params[:userid].is_a? Integer
```

And from reading up quickly on Rails, this should work, at least in theory I suppose. The route is setup properly because I checked it and had the page read back the `:userid`. There are no errors being thrown from the console, but here is the read out when using `/account/jonathan/settings` as the route:

> Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-28 23:04:24 -0400
>     ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
>   Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
>     Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.1ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 124ms (Views: 117.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
>
> Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-28 23:04:31 -0400
>   Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
>     Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 14.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
>
> Started GET "/account/jonathan/settings" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-28 23:04:32 -0400
>   Processing by AccountController#settings as HTML
>     Parameters: {"userid"=>"jonathan"}
>     Rendered text template (0.0ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
>
> Started GET "/account/jonathan/settings" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-28 23:04:38 -0400
>   Processing by AccountController#settings as HTML
>     Parameters: {"userid"=>"jonathan"}
>     Rendered text template (0.0ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

And when using `/account/1/settings` as the route:

> Started GET "/account/1/settings" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-28 23:27:00 -0400
>   Processing by AccountController#settings as HTML
>     Parameters: {"userid"=>"1"}
>     Rendered text template (0.0ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
>
> Started GET "/account/1/settings" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-28 23:27:00 -0400
>   Processing by AccountController#settings as HTML
>     Parameters: {"userid"=>"1"}
>     Rendered text template (0.0ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

I have tried using a route such as `/account/1/settings` and `/account/jon/settings` and neither show whats wrong.

Comment: In `{"userid"=>"jonathan"} `, the value is a String. So, what's the problem?

Comment: @CodeGnome Even when replacing Jonathan with 1 it still never renders

Comment: Because `"1"` is a String, too. This whole question seems like an X/Y problem. What functional issue are you really trying to solve by having a condition render based on `params[:userid]`?

Comment: Im trying to use the param as a way to get a users access token for authentication before being able to access the page, other wise give them an error, or send them to a login page.

Comment: 1) That's insecure. Don't roll your own authentication; use devise or similar. 2) If you don't care about real security: `redirect_to :login if params[:userid].blank?` ensures that a *userid* is present.

Comment: Im still just learning the grasp of Rails, but the control statements are still fuzzy. Im obviously not going to use something just as a user id for authentication, but messing around with routes and different things are better to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

You are trying to redirect based on the presence of a value in the params hash. Per [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834997/rails-unless-statement-failure?noredirect=1#comment53506513_32834997) above, the real underlying issue you're trying to resolve is:

> Im trying to use the param as a way to get a users access token for authentication before being able to access the page, other wise give them an error, or send them to a login page.

Rendering nothing won't do that. Even if the logic succeeds the way you envision, that won't redirect them.

Furthermore, [params hash values *are always strings*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#hash-and-array-parameters). As a result, branching based on an Integer as you currently do won't work.

### Solution

#### Use a Well-Tested Authentication/Authorization Scheme

Authentication and authorization schemes are hard to get right. While you should feel free to apply them according to the needs of your application, rolling your own authentication mechanism is generally a really bad idea.

As a rule of thumb, you should use a security gem that is actively developed and is in widespread use, so that you can benefit from all the people who have vetted it for design effectiveness and bugs. Avoid security gems with low bus-factors unless you have a deeply compelling reason. Currently, [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) is your best bet, but you can select from any widely-adopted [authentication](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=rails%20authentication) or [authorization](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization) gem that suits your needs.

#### Fix Your Branching Bug

If you don't really care about security, and just want to fix your branching logic, you could call [String#blank?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-blank-3F) to determine whether *params[:userid]* has a value. For example:

```
redirect_to :login if params[:userid].blank?
```

If you've implemented devise, there are a number of helpers to take care of these things for you, such as:

- `before_action :authenticate_user!` to handle redirects for unauthenticated users.
- `user_signed_in?` to return a Boolean based on the authentication status of the current user.

See [Controller filters and helpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) for more details.

Comment: I'll look into devise more. I'm used to PHP and rolled some auth by guides, but the tutorials I'm watching haven't talked much about control flow or params, so I'm kind of trying as I go.

Answer (score 0):

Next time paste your error message for easier help.

Now, what I would try is to add some parenthesis for human and machine clarity:

```
render(nothing: true) unless params[:userid].is_a?(Integer)
```

Try that and update your answer with the error message.

Comment: Im getting no errors, but here Ill paste the read out from the console. And my IDE was showing warnings about parenthesis around certain statements, so I figured best practice was to not have them

Answer (score 0):

I think params[:userid] is a String, like `params = {userid: "1"}`

You can write a method in controller or in Integer class and call it

```
render nothing: true unless is_integer?(params[:userid])

protected
def is_integer?(value)
  value.to_s.to_i == value
end
```

Comment: Its still not rendering anything

Comment: `userid = "jonathan"`, it's not an integer, so render nothing is correct.
But `/account/1/settings` should work, could you post your `settings` action

Comment: That is correct, but when replacing jonathan with a number such as 1 it still doesn't render